# unexpected results to use nils to fit power function in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

The problem in James stewart, "Calculus Early Transcendentals', section 1.2, 27

To main idea is to use a power function to y as a function of x where

x = c(10, 104, 8958, 11423, 76184, 114511)

y = c(5, 9, 40, 39, 84, 76)

The answer provided by textbook is y = 2.3356 x^{0.3072}.

However, I use the following R code to fit curve

```
x = c(10, 104, 8958, 11423, 76184, 114511)
y = c(5, 9, 40, 39, 84, 76)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
fitCurve <- nls( y ~ I(a*(x^n)), data = df, start = list(a=1, n=0), trace = T)
```

and I obtain the fitting function as y = 2.5823367 x^{0.2985165}.

The scatter graph (red line: textbook solution, black: nls results) shows that nls results are quite unexpected. I have no idea what happened! [image: unexpected fitting function result]

I have also tried to use log function as follows to fit, but the results are the same.

```
logy = log10(y)
logx = log10(x)

fitLine <- lm(logy ~ logx)
loga = fitLine$coefficients[[1]]
a = exp(loga)
n = fitLine$coefficients[[2]]
```

Complete codes:

```
# fitting to power function
# y = a x^ n
# two methods: 1. use nls package (nonlinear least square) 2. logy = loga + nlogx, lm (logy ~ logx)

x = c(10, 104, 8958, 11423, 76184, 114511)
y = c(5, 9, 40, 39, 84, 76)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
fitCurve <- nls( y ~ I(a*(x^n)), data = df, start = list(a=1, n=0), trace = T)
summary(fitCurve)
solA = a*(754^n)
y_myOwn = a*x^n

# method 2
logy = log10(y)
logx = log10(x)

fitLine <- lm(logy ~ logx)
loga = fitLine$coefficients[[1]]
a = exp(loga)
n = fitLine$coefficients[[2]]

predictY = a*(x^n)
plot(x, predictY)
#plot(x, y)

solB = a*(754^n)
solB

y_textbook = 2.3356*(x^0.3072)
plot(x, y, col="green")
lines(x, y_textbook, col="red")
lines(x, y_myOwn, col="black")
```

Comment: Did you actually calculate the sum of the squared difference between the expected and observed values for the two fits? The R estimates are smaller: `sum((coef(fitCurve)[1]*x^coef(fitCurve)[2]-y)^2); sum((2.3356*x^0.3072-y)^2)`. Since you're trying to minimize the sum of squares it seems like R gives a better answer. Are you sure you drew the fit lines (color) correctly? Also, the version of the text i can see online has different X values than you do.

Comment: I use:  y_textbook = 2.3356*(x^0.3072);
plot(x, y, col="green");
lines(x, y_textbook, col="red");
to draw. In fact, I am not familiar how nls package works. I didn't calculate the square values, but from the graph, black line does not fit green points as red line does. The quiz is from 7 Edition.

Comment: Then I think your black line is wrong. How did you plot that? But that doesn't really matter. You're still going to get a different, better answer in R.

Comment: I plot black line by: 
x = c(10, 104, 8958, 11423, 76184, 114511);
y = c(5, 9, 40, 39, 84, 76); df <- data.frame(x, y);
fitCurve <- nls( y ~ I(a*(x^n)), data = df, start = list(a=1, n=0), trace = T);
y_myOwn = a*x^n;
lines(x, y_myOwn, col="black");

Comment: That code doesn't redefine `a` or `n`. Either you've left something out or I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: In fact, I am not quite familiar with R. I just use this to learn Calculus. I also see the progress to converge like the following:
15559 :  1 0
14312.08 :  0.2351245 0.2549297
11797.26 :  0.3604080 0.3017206
9154.12 :  0.6385917 0.2987891
5233.814 :  1.1246278 0.2984997
1434.643 :  1.8534710 0.2985199
169.0016 :  2.5823443 0.2985148
169.0016 :  2.5823367 0.2985165
I am not sure which part I have messed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use the predict method I get a sensible plot, unlike your result for which you did not provide the plotting methods:

```
> png(); plot(x,y)
> lines(x=x, y=predict(fitCurve), col="red")
> dev.off()
```

[image]

```
> formula(fitCurve)
y ~ I(a * (x^n))
> summary(fitCurve)

Formula: y ~ I(a * (x^n))

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
a  2.58234    1.31025   1.971  0.12005   
n  0.29852    0.04612   6.473  0.00294 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.5 on 4 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.802e-07
```

Comment: thanks a lot, BondedDust. I follow your steps and get the correct results. It's more accurate in R results.

Comment: The book's solution is what you get if you fit `lm(log(y)~log(x))` (and exponentiate the intercept), which is a different statistical model but also reasonable under some circumstances.